# How to bind values in different fields when clicking a list which is created by ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, onclick

I am new to angular JS.I have a view in which there are some title buttons.The title buttons are created using ng-repeat..On click of the title button I want username and comment area of the form to display  certain values.I have written an onClick function inside the "li" tag from which I have created the Titles.Help will be appreciated
 
 I have a view like this.[image]
My HTML looks like this

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
            <h1>User Entry Form</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <label>Username :</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" ng-disabled="disableinput" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <label>Select an option :</label>
                    <select ng-model="selectedGame" ng-disabled="disablelist" ng-change="checkin()" ng-options="gname.Name for gname in games">
                        <option ng-model="optionValue" value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="checklistbox col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="checkBox" ng-click="checked()">sample1
                </div>
                <div class="radiobox col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <input type="radio" name="abc" value="male" ng-model="maleButton" ng-click="disable()">Male
                    <input type="radio" name="abc" value="female" ng-model="femalebutton" ng-click="enable()">Female
                </div>                                          
             </div>
                <div class="row">                        
                    <div class="form-commentbox col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <label>Comment:</label>
                                <textarea ng-model="commentArea" id="styled" placeholder="Enter your valuable comments ..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="buttonscontainer col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <div class="resetbox col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="savebox col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <button class="btn btn-success"><a href="Listpage.html">Ok</a></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```

This is my JS file

```
var app = angular.module("listApp", []);
app.controller("listCntrl", function ($scope) {
 $scope.listNames = [   
    { id: 1, BoxNo: 'Title1', Subhead: 'Sub 1', FirstName: "Saju", selectedGame: 'football', checkBox: true, maleButton: true },
        { id: 2, BoxNo: 'Title 2', Subhead: 'Sub 2', FirstName: "Jayesh", selectedGame: 'hockey', checkBox: false, maleButton: true },
        { id: 3, BoxNo: 'Title 3', Subhead: 'Sub 3', FirstName: "Soja", selectedGame: 'cricket', checkBox: true, femalebutton: true },
        { id: 4, BoxNo: 'Title 4', Subhead: 'Sub 4', FirstName: "Manu", selectedGame: 'volleyball', checkBox: true, maleButton: true },
        { id: 5, BoxNo: 'Title 5', Subhead: 'Sub 5', FirstName: "Alan", selectedGame: 'badminton', checkBox: true, maleButton: true }
        ];
$scope.selectedCustomer = function (sc) {
        var value = sc;
        selectedCard = value;    
    };
```

Comment: Please paste the code you tried, and also paste the li loop. create a fiddle if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Angular's internal ng-repeat indexing $index in your onClick function for the li element, based on the index change the values of the form in your controller.

```
$scope.firstName = $scope.listNames[$index].firstName;
$scope.selectedGame = $scope.listNames[$index].selectedGame;
.
.
```

*Tip:* Making the form object **myForm** which will hold all the values of the form will make things more modular. You should also modify your HTML accordingly. For example:

```
myForm = $scope.listNames[$index];
```